# Airflow Dag not running on scheduled interval

Tags: airflow

I am testing a simple dag to run on scheduled interval which is at 6 UTC on every Friday and Saturday('0 6 * * 5,6').
But the dag did not triggered on 6 am on Friday.
I know that Friday's instance will run on Saturday and Saturday's on Friday.

What can I do so that it will run Friday's instance on Friday only? or any work around?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def create_txt():
f=open("/home/abc/test1.txt","w+")
for i in range(10):
    f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
f.close()

default_args = {
'owner': 'abc',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2020, 6, 24),
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
'catchup': False
}

with DAG('python_test',
     default_args=default_args,schedule_interval='0 6 * * 5,6'
     ) as dag:

create_txt = PythonOperator(task_id='python_test',
                python_callable=create_txt)
```

Comment: By design Airflow run DAGs for the previous schedule, so if there is no necessity of running DAG once a day, you can run the DAG twice on friday and saturday so that you get run friday on friday. Something like this could be done ```schedule_interval='0 6,7 * * 5,6'```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the scheduler health,
2. Try to increase the scheduler timeout
3. Make sure there are no other dags importing the same modules in and around the same time.
4. Suggesting you to import os,sys modules.
5. If the dag is going to be executed for the first time, then consider giving a manual execution for the first time.